# eclipse android graphic editor not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just created a new android project in eclipse and added a relative layout. 
I can add controls using XML but I can't add any controls using the graphic editor.

My current code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click on a widget - say a button, a black circle with a diagonal bar in it shows briefly then disappears, and I cannot drag the control onto the editor.

If I create the control in code, it shows up ok, but I can't select it with a left click, only right click. Then once selected it cannot be moved, and moving the handles does not resize the control. It can only be be deleted.
Any clues as to why this might be?
I'm using version 4.2.2
I don't knoiw what else to include that might be of assistance.

Comment: I notice that in the error log I have an entry that says Unhandled event loop exception.

Comment: I just tried a pure vanilla test project - all defaults and get the same result except with an additional error - Failed to load properties file for project 'test01'.  I think I may need to reinstall eclipse.

Comment: Indeed.. Its 2016 and I still have that same behavior with Eclipse Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

I'd assume we are doing something wrong, but I have just opened a sample app and this happens.  I have not observed these issues with Eclipse back in 2013.